# Session data renders incorrectly in template

Tags: templates, session, playframework, session-variables

I store `user.displayName` in the session, when users authenticate:

```
session.put("udn", user.displayName);
```

and the template renders it using:

```
${session.udn}
```

but strange things occur:

1. login as "Sam", display "Sam";
2. logout;
3. login as "Jim", display "Sam", too!
4. restart play;
5. login as "Jim", display "Jim";
6. logout;
7. login as "Sam", display "Jim", too!

That is, it always display the first logged in user's displayName.

debug just after the session.put:

```
session.put("udn", user.displayName);
```

`Logger.debug("udn:\t" + session.get("udn"));`

it prints correctly:

- login as Sam, prints "udn:Sam";
- login as Jim, prints "udn:Jim"

also, I checked the cookie:
PLAY_SESSION contains `%00udn%3A` + correct value + `%00`:

- login as Sam, PLAY_SESSION contains `%00udn%3ASam%00`
- login as Jim, PLAY_SESSION contains `%00udn%3AJim%00`

How do I display the correct value? (my play app depends on play 1.2.3 & Secure module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `${session.get("udn")}` in your template. The [implicit](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/templates#implicits) `session` variable is just an instance of [play.mvc.Scope.Session](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play%2Fmvc%2FScope.Session.html); there's no magic in place that would allow syntax like `${session.udn}`. I'm not sure why that prints anything at all.